# How to return data of Promise then in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components, filestack

I'm using filestack for uploading files. I just want to create a service for uploading so that I can reuse in any components. But I have a problem with my code.

This is a function in the service file

```
uploadFiles(file,size) {
    let fsClient = filestack.init(fsKey);
    let fileAccepted = file;
    let maxSize = size;
    let fileOptions = {
      fromSources:["local_file_system"],
      accept: fileAccepted,
      maxFiles:1,
      minFiles:1,
      transformations:{
        crop:true,
        circle:false
      },
      maxSize:maxSize
    };
    let fileRes = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fsClient.pick(fileOptions).then((response) => {
        if(response) {
          console.log(response);
          resolve(response);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    });
    return fileRes;
  }
```

My Calling function in component

```
this._fs.uploadFiles(fileAccepted,maxSize).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
});
```

I get the response in service function, but not in the component. Where is the problem and suggest a way to accomplish to reuse the function in components

Answer (score 0):

The function fsClient.pick() seems to return a promise, so instead of wrapping the call fsClient.pick(fileOptions) inside another promise, you could just return this call from the uploadFiles function. So just return fsClient.pick(fileOptions). The code in the component remains unchanged.

Comment: I tried returning fsClient.pick(fileOptions), still not getting respone in then function

Comment: Rather strange. Where is this code placed in the component : this._fs.uploadFiles() ? Is it inside a lifecycle hook ?

Comment: @Manush can you please post your last try, too?